# flutter aplication don't run in my emulator phone in debug but not in my phone

Tags: flutter

im working at a flutter app, and how i sayed my app don't run my apk in my telephone and to get a test i send the app to some friends, but i dont know what happend

and i dont know what i must to show, so i gotta show he http response and where it is invocated

```
sincroniza.dart
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, unused_local_variable

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../src/database.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'aires_model.dart';

var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer --kjsiweuHHDNNWESNNAKSKDNN34556523433656KNNNNQQQQQQQ'
};

sincroniza(context) async {
  // Comprobar la conexión a Internet
  var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    print('El dispositivo no tiene conexión a Internet.');

    return;
  }

  final endpoints = [
    "capacidades.php",
    "refrigerantes.php",
    "tipo_equipos.php",
    "marcas.php"
  ];
  var headers = {
    'Authorization':
        'Bearer --kjsiweuHHDNNWESNNAKSKDNN34556523433656KNNNNQQQQQQQ'
  };

  for (var endpoint in endpoints) {
    print(endpoint);
    var request = http.Request(
        'GET',
        Uri.parse(
            'https://www.intecproyectosysoluciones.com/api/$endpoint?us=YWRtaW4='));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final String responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      final List<dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(responseString);

      switch (endpoint) {
        case "capacidades.php":
          try {
            // Código para manejar la respuesta del endpoint de capacidades
            for (var item in jsonResponse) {
              Capacidad capacidad = Capacidad(
                  id: int.parse(item['id']), descripcion: item['descripcion']);
              bool resultado =
                  await IntecSoftwareDB.instance.insert_capacidad(capacidad);
            }
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content:
                    Text('Las capacidades se han actualizado exitosamente.'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
          } catch (error) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text(
                    'Ha ocurrido un error al manejar la respuesta del endpoint de capacidades: $error'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
          }

          break;

        case "refrigerantes.php":
          // Código para manejar la respuesta del endpoint de refrigerantes
          print("Respuesta del endpoint de refrigerantes:");
          for (var item in jsonResponse) {
            Refrigerante refrigerante = Refrigerante(
                id: int.parse(item['id']), descripcion: item['descripcion']);
            bool resultado = await IntecSoftwareDB.instance
                .insert_refrigerante(refrigerante);
            print(resultado);
          }
          break;

        case "tipo_equipos.php":
          // Código para manejar la respuesta del endpoint de tipo_equipos
          print("Respuesta del endpoint de tipo_equipos:");
          for (var item in jsonResponse) {
            TipoEquipo equipo = TipoEquipo(
                descripcion: item['descripcion'], id: int.parse(item['id']));
            bool resultado =
                await IntecSoftwareDB.instance.insert_tipo_equipo(equipo);
          }
          break;

        case "marcas.php":
          // Código para manejar la respuesta del endpoint de marcas
          print("Respuesta del endpoint de marcas:");
          for (var item in jsonResponse) {
            Marca marca = Marca(
                descripcion: item['descripcion'], id: int.parse(item['id']));
            bool resultado = await IntecSoftwareDB.instance.insert_marca(marca);
          }
          break;

        default:
          // Código para manejar cualquier otro endpoint que no esté en la lista
          print("Endpoint desconocido: $endpoint");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

sincronizaTipoEquipos() async {
  final endpoints = [
    "capacidades.php",
    "refrigerantes.php",
    "tipo_equipos.php",
    "marcas.php"
  ];
  var headers = {
    'Authorization':
        'Bearer --kjsiweuHHDNNWESNNAKSKDNN34556523433656KNNNNQQQQQQQ'
  };
  var request = http.Request(
      'GET',
      Uri.parse(
          'https://www.intecproyectosysoluciones.com/api/tipo_equipos.php?us=YWRtaW4='));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final String responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    final List<dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(responseString);

    for (var item in jsonResponse) {
      print(item);
      final tipoEquipo = TipoEquipo(
        id: int.parse(item['id']),
        descripcion: item['descripcion'],
      );
      var resultado =
          await IntecSoftwareDB.instance.insert_tipo_equipo(tipoEquipo);
      if (resultado) {
        print('se insertó con exito');
      } else {
        print('ya ha habido una inserción');
      }
    }
  }
}

sincronizaMarcas() async {
  // sincroniza las marcas
  var request = http.Request(
      'GET',
      Uri.parse(
          'https://www.intecproyectosysoluciones.com/api/marcas.php?us=YWRtaW4='));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final String responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    final List<dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(responseString);

    for (var item in jsonResponse) {
      print(item);
      final marca = Marca(
        id: int.parse(item['id']),
        descripcion: item['descripcion'],
      );
      var resultado = await IntecSoftwareDB.instance.insert_marca(marca);
      if (resultado) {
        print('se insertó con exito');
      } else {
        print('ya ha habido una inserción');
      }
    }
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}
```

and this the widget who is calling

```
class BotonAnimado extends StatefulWidget {
  const BotonAnimado({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BotonAnimadoState createState() => _BotonAnimadoState();
}

class _BotonAnimadoState extends State<BotonAnimado>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      vsync: this,
    )..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _controller.reset();
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: const ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Color(0xFF2494CE))),
        onPressed: () async {
          _controller.repeat();
          await sincroniza(context).then((value) {
            _controller.stop();
            _controller.reset();
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 3.1415926535897932,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i tryed to change the direcction run a fisical drive but when i run the app is working at debug mode, but when disconect the divice nothing is working.

the true i don't have nothing to share about this is did you need some details can comment this cause i don't get any idea about what the wrong.